# Porting from Python with NP to Java - can't multiply sequence by non-int type of "list" when passing to np.sum

Tags: java, python, arrays, numpy

I have two two-dimensional list/array variables, values and weighs. Both are lists of floats. The code I'm porting has the line:

```
weighted_sum_values = np.sum(values * weights, axis=0)
```

When I run this line to determine the behavior, the error I get is:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

So, while I'm fairly certain np.sum will return a one-dimensional list, I don't understand why it's telling me I can't multiply these two arrays before passing it to np.sum - What's going on exactly, and how can I port the intended function to Java? Will I have to make a temporary 2D list of the multiplied values first before summing them? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After further playing around with it, it looks like it's numpy's way of multiplying two arrays, element by element.